# Linux Java program X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but

Tags: java, linux, xvfb

I'm aware that this is a recurrent question but I haven't found any answer yet.

I'm on a linux server (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) and I have a java application that calls another one to do some operation, the first one runs with no problem, but the second one use GUI and when I call it I get the infamous error " No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it. ". I already have a Xvfb instance running and I exported DISPLAY.

```
Xvfb :99 &
export DISPLAY=:99
```

If I do

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

I get `:99`

I can run the called java application by command line and it works, but when it's another java application that calls it, it doesn't work. Why it doesn't "see" the DISPLAY variable when I call the jar from another java application ? And how do I fix this ?

NOTE : I use `ProcessBuilder` to call it.

Comment: Do you actually need a display at all? If not you can run the JVM with `-Djava.awt.headless=true`

Comment: No I don't require to see the display, but the application needs it (poorly coded) and running it with `-Djava.awt.headless=true` doesn't work either.

Comment: Unless you clear it, ProcessBulder will pass the caller's environment to the called process.

Comment: What do you mean ? They're on the same environment

Comment: Can you be more precise about "doesn't work"?

Comment: I get this : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at com.prodevcoind.myapp.gui.MainDesktop.main(MainDesktop.java:198) Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this actually solved the problem :

processBuilder.environment().put("DISPLAY", ":99");

Answer (score 1):

Since you use a `ProcessBuilder` and don't require a display, you may try and do this before you `.start()` the process:

```
pb.environment().remove("DISPLAY");
```

Yes, that's right, `environment()` returns a *read write view* of the process' environment variables...